# Commerce Server 2009 with SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, microsoft-commerce-server

I'm trying to decide to between using MojoPortal for my organizations CMS or Commerce Server 2009 with SharePoint 2010.

We already have SharePoint 2010 for our intranet. In that thinking, perhaps it would make sense to deploy the same technology?

We do not have a lot of traffic but do need basic e-commerce functionality.

I haven't really found a lot of documentation for Commerce Server 2009. It would have to share the same server with SharePoint 2010. I'm not worried about that because of the low traffic.

I'm worried about how difficult it is to install. Is it a nightmare product to install or is it pretty straightforward? Is it unrealistic for it to share a server with SharePoint 2010, even in relatively low traffic?

Any experiences with administering MojoPortal?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been working with Commerce Server for 6 years since 2002 version.

There is no problem in running your solution in the same SharePoint server of your intranet portal, since you have low traffic prevision. In regard to installation issues you should have in mind that it's not a simple product and the configuration usually takes some time. I think it's not a "nightmare" but not that simple too.

If you wish you could start you solution based on Starter Site which can be installed and then customized. The Starter Site have almost all features that you need in a simple e-commerce site.

Regards,
Alex